# Difference between if let Some and match

Tags: rust

Trying to understand what is wrong in

```
fn set_inpt_port_values1(&mut self, input_port_values: HashMap<u8, u8>) {
    if let Some(mut io_handler) = self.io_handler {
       io_handler.set_input_ports_values(input_port_values);
    }
}
```

Getting

```
cannot move out of `self.io_handler.0` which is behind a mutable referencerustcE0507
i808x.rs(2333, 21): data moved here
i808x.rs(2333, 21): move occurs because `io_handler` has type `Box<dyn IoHandler>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
i808x.rs(2333, 39): consider borrowing here
```

On the other side, the similar function

```
fn set_inpt_port_values(&mut self, input_port_values: HashMap<u8, u8>) {
    match &mut self.io_handler {
        Some(io_handler) => {
            io_handler.set_input_ports_values(input_port_values);
        }
        _ => (),
    }
}
```

works/compiles fine (likely `set_inpt_port_values` doesn't need to be mutable).

The field io_handler is `Option<Box<dyn IoHandler>>`

```
pub trait IoHandler {
    fn in_op(&mut self, port: u8) -> u8;
    fn out_op(&mut self, port: u8, byte: u8);
    fn set_input_ports_values(&mut self, input_port_values: HashMap<u8, u8>);
}
```

Comment: If you write `if let Some(io_handler) = &mut self.io_handler`, you'll have the direct equivalent of the match, and it should compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, in this statement

```rust
if let Some(mut io_handler) = self.io_handler {
```

you're trying to move `self.io_handler` into a mutable variable called `io_handler`. This isn't allowed because that would leave `self.io_handler` uninitialized.

On the other hand, this `match`

```rust
match &mut self.io_handler {
        Some(io_handler) => {
```

matches on a `&mut Option<Box<dyn IoHandler>>` and moves a *mutable reference* to `self.io_handler` into an immutable variable called `io_handler`.

You can achieve the same thing with an if let, by using the `ref` keyword:

```rust
if let Some(ref mut io_handler) = self.io_handler {
```

This will now try to borrow a mutable reference to whatever is inside that box.

Comment: You could also achieve the same thing with `if let Some(io_handler) = &mut self.io_handler {` (`ref` on the left side is equivalent to `&` on the right side) but I agree that the explicit usage of `ref` enables more subtleties when there are many variables to extract.